# Truffle contract size limit is severely impacting the functionality of my contracts. Is there a way around this?

Tags: solidity, truffle-compile

Basically what the title says. I have in total 4 contracts. 2 of them serve one of the rest as what I call data banks and this one is imported and acted upon by the remaining one to instantiate the master contract. Pardon the confusing naming.

The thing is I need these functions to bring fruition to my project but it this master contract which imports the contract below it won't compile.
Is there any way around this? Or something which works for you in such scenarios? Any suggestions?

Thanks.